# Can Blob URLs be considered as a solution to prevent users from copying the images from inside the developers console?

Tags: javascript, url, blob

As we all know, if we read the image (or video) files as a binary object and then make a URL to these objects, we can then display the files with these blob URLs inside the HTML which can not be accessed in another window or tab since it only exists in the current session. As a result, the user can not simply save the file (for example we can not simply download youtube videos since their video tags have blob URLs as their sources).

So can we say this is a way to prevent users from stealing the sensitive files using the developer's console? If so, why so many websites do not do that? I know many websites that have copy-righted images or sell wallpapers but you can simply download their files from the console.
Or is something wrong with this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not at all no. The file is on their computer already, and they can very well save it, be it an image or even a video, feeding the HTML element with a blob:// URL doesn't prevent any "save As" actions:

```js
fetch( "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png" )
  .then( resp => resp.blob() )
  .then( blob => {
    console.log( 'img loaded' );
    const elem = document.querySelector( 'img' );
    elem.src = URL.createObjectURL( blob );
  } );

fetch( "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/BBH_gravitational_lensing_of_gw150914.webm" )
  .then( resp => resp.blob() )
  .then( blob => {
    console.log( 'video loaded' );
    const elem = document.querySelector( 'video' );
    elem.src = URL.createObjectURL( blob );
  } );
```

```html
Try to right click "save As..." these two media:
<img>
<video controls></video>
```

Revoking the blob:// URL once loaded could make it a bit harder, but even then, if you look at the Network Panel of your dev tools, you'll see the original request from which the Blob has been generated and from where your users will be able to scrape your data.

#### YouTube is not using a blob:// URL to prevent downloads

If they really did want to make it harder to download their videos, they'd protect it with DRMs and would be using the [EME API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Encrypted_Media_Extensions_API), but they're not.
The blob:// URL you see in YouTube's video doesn't point to a Blob, but to a [MediaSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource) object. They do use this API to be able to serve adaptive contents, i.e to be able to send a lower quality of the same media on the fly when the connection quality worsens.
It has absolutely nothing to do with any protection, and a quick search on the web will tell you it's quite simple to find back the original file**s** YT is streaming.

Comment: thanks for the answer. well, I had no idea about MediaSources till now. I was wondering if we somehow prevent downloading by right click (e.g by using images as backgrounds instead of image tags) and feed those background images with blob URLs, then we can make saving the images/videos as hard as possible for the user.

Comment: btw, I wonder why no one answered my question for 6 days. looks like the question was either so advanced or so dumb,