# How to convert html video src url to blob

Tags: html5-video, blob

I have a video, for example:

**https://mywebsite.com/myvideo.webm**

Instead of using that url in the <video scr=

i want the video src url to be for example

**blob:https://mywebsite.com/76e7f89c-ecd3-455d-a5eb-93eed74a2e25**

How to do that?

Comment: You don't because there is no point at all doing that. To do so you'd need to fetch the whole file in memory, and if your goal was to prevent someone from downloading your file, then they would only have to check their network logs and find the original resource. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62042789/can-blob-urls-be-considered-as-a-solution-to-prevent-users-from-copying-the-imag/62125040#62125040